# Which native mobile device capabilities can be accessed through a browser?

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, mobile, mobile-safari, mobile-website

I'm creating a chart which lists native capabilities for iOS, Android and Windows phones, and whether these can be accessed through the phone's mobile browser. I'm looking at only the latest OS versions for each.

Can anyone confirm or give input into how accurate what I've found so far is? I'm especially unsure about Windows phones.

[image: Device Capabitilies Chart]

Comment: If you write an Android app with it's own `WebView` and provide it with a Javascript interface you can basically get the back-end Java to do anything you want from a web page.

Comment: I mainly want to compare building an app that is downloaded, vs a webapp that is accessed through a URL. Which is why I'm not considering hybrid apps- those would be in the same category as native apps for this exercise.

Comment: There are multiple OS versions of each of these, and the answers will differ for each.

Comment: I'm looking for info on the latest OS versions only. I will edit the post with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow this is a really useful chart. Glad you thought of it!

iOS things I noticed

- you can spawn the message app for sms using sms:// protocol handler on an anchor tag
- ios browser has full multitouch!
- 'fast graphics api' is vague...but ya canvas is slugglish. webgl is coming tho!
- 'fluid animation' can be achieved with css transforms
- ios supports input types date, datetime, month, time, range
- push notifications are not doable but alerts are
- 'interact with other apps' also doable w/ protocol handlers

Android

- as w/ ios you can spawn the sms app w/ sms:// protocol
- android system browser has multitouch; but its got a bug that only shows one touch. chrome has proper multitouch..
- graphics and animation are doable as per ios
- interact w/ apps also possible w/ protocol handlers (and intents)

Windows Phone

- accurate but that will change this fall when windows phone 8 ships

And hey, what about BlackBerry!

Comment: Hey Brian, how are push notifications possible on iOS?